# ASP.NET: GridView Select Button: How to change the button's properties programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, select, button

I have a gridview with a Select button in every row. How do I change the properties of this button programmatically? For example if the Party value of the row is Republican, I want the Select button to be Red; otherwise I want it to be Blue.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx):

```
<asp:Button ... BackColor=<%# Eval("Party") = "Republican" ? "Red" : "Blue" %> ... />
```

Here, the `BackColor` property will take the appropriate value based on the `Party` value whenever a `RowDataBound` event gets fired ..

Answer (score 2):

In your code (assuming server side) you need to get a reference to that row and then call FindControl passing in your buttons name. Then you can set whatever properties on it (css class, color, etc)

See this posting for details:

[Accessing the different controls inside a GridView control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AccessingControlsInsideGr.aspx)